# Generic datatemplate

Tags: .net, wpf

I am new to WPF and I am trying to create a generic datatemplate which I can use in Gridview Columns cell template.

In my datatemplate I am using a textbox, but I am not sure how to make a generic text binding which I can set when I am creating datagrid column. My datatemplate xaml is below

```
< DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridCelltemplate">
<DockPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Content.Text}" Height="Auto"/>
    </DockPanel>
< /DataTemplate>
```

The Listview which I have created is

```
< ListView Name="empListView"
                  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=1}}"
                  Height="250"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="4,5,6,0"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">

            <ListView.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="320"
                                  ShadowDepth="5"
                                  BlurRadius="10"/>
            </ListView.Effect>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
< ListView.View>

< GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Employee Name" Width="Auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridCelltemplate}">

                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date Of Birth" Width="Auto"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="Auto"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="Auto"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Now when I run this I do not get any data until I specify the Binding path to property of the collection which this list view is attached. So I have to create separate datatemplate for each column and specify the path for each columns. Again if I apply DisplayMemberBinding template does not work. 
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like your code is incomplete (?)

Comment: Yah I just reformatted code..please have a look now.

Comment: Hi, your code is still incomplete. Check your debug output, it will usually tell you who the culprit is.

Comment: I am sorry, the code is not complete, I just pasted some part of code which I though would be easy to understand my question. Please let me know what exactly you want. If you want I can email you the code file so that you can check. Let me know you email id if possible. Does that help ?